# Uncaught TypeError: p.appendChild is not a function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm taking a class on Ajax and this very simple script is throwing an error I don't understand. I keep getting an Uncaught Type Error saying that the appendChild method is not a function.

The function I'm working through is meant to asynchronously load the contents of a text file into a 'p' tag when the link is clicked.

I'm somewhat new to javascript so it's probably something simple I've missed, I'd appreciate any help in understanding what I'm doing wrong.

```
(function(){

var link = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

link.onclick = function(){

    //create xhr object
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // handle the "onreadystatechange" event
    /*
    xhr.readysState property values
    0 = Uninitialized
    1 = Loading
    2 = Loaded
    3 = Interactive - server is sending a response
    4 = Complete
    */
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if ( (xhr.readyState == 4) && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 304) ) {

            xhr.responseText;

            var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
            var pText = document.createTextNode(xhr.responseText);

            console.log(p);
            console.log(pText);

            p.appendChild(pText);
            body.appendChild(p);
        }

    };

    // open the request
    /* arguments: 
    1. type of request a (GET or POST) 
    2. path 
    3. asynchronaus request? (true || false)*/
    xhr.open('GET', 'files/ajax.txt', true);  

    // send the request
    xhr.send(null)

    return false; // disable default behavior of link
};

})();
```

I've created a jsFiddle to show my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/scottm1164/656edjsf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` is a `NodeList`; I think you meant `document.createElement` rather than `document.getElementsByTagName`.

```
var p = document.createElement('p');
```

Comment: That was it, Thank you! I should have seen that!

Answer (score 9):

[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a `NodeList`. Therefore, you have to access individual items with an index like

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
```

The reason it was giving you

> p.appendChild is not a function

is because `appendChild` is not a function of type `NodeList`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, however when I when I add the index to the p variable as you suggest, I end up with another error:

_Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined_

Comment: @scottM, are you sure you have existing 'p' elements when you do document.getElementsByTagName('p')?

Comment: @scottM, perhaps like minitech said, you meant to create a p element?

Comment: Yep, it was the createElement that was missing, Minitech caught the error.

Answer (score 1):

`p` is an array of elements. You should select just one. In your fiddle, you don't even have 1.